# Making and drawing an image C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

Is there any way in C# that I can take an empty image and for example draw lines onto it? If possible can you show me an example on how to do this? I've seen something like this before but I don't know to much on how to do it and everywhere online I found was doing it from a pre existing image, then drawing over it. I don't want to have to load anything, just a nice little thing for an interface I'm working on. I know it sounds like I'm asking for code, but all I'm asking for is how to draw an image without loading anything.

Comment: All I asked was for someone to help me figure this whole thing out.

Comment: Arun C.B The problem that I'm in is that I don't want to load any image, I just want to draw one without any pre made data.

Comment: Google the System.Drawing namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GDI+ (and more specifically the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class):

```
// Load an existing image into a Graphics object
using (var image = Image.FromFile(@"c:\work\input.png"))
using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    // Draw a line on this image from (0x0) to (50x50)
    gfx.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 50, 50);

    // save the resulting Graphics object to a new file
    using (var output = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\work\output.png"))
    {
        image.Save(output, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

And if you want to create a new image:

```
// Create a new image 50x50 in size
using (var image = new Bitmap(50, 50))
using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    // Draw a line on this image from (0x0) to (50x50)
    gfx.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 50, 50);

    // save the resulting Graphics object to a new file
    using (var output = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\work\output.png"))
    {
        image.Save(output, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking how to do this without loading anything.

Comment: Sure, then just create a new image. I have updated my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: +1 nice answer @DarinDimitrov as always

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a panel on the form.
Buffer is a `Bitmap`.

Then use the `panel1_MouseDown`-Event to draw something:

```
     using (Graphics bufferGrph = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
        {
            bufferGrph.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 1), 1, 1, 100, 100); //Example
        }   
        panel1.Invalidate();
```

Then use the `panel1_Paint` - Event to draw the image on the panel with:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(buffer, Point.Empty);
```

To save the content of the panel use the Control:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width,panel1.Height);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.Bounds);
bmp.Save(@"MYPATH HERE");
```